# Excel loop copy paste until blank cell in column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy data in column B starting at cell B5 and paste into cell E2. Loop this until a blank cell in column B overwriting E2 every time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, rB As Range

    Set rB = Range("B5:B" & Rows.Count)

    For Each r In rB
        If r.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        r.Copy Range("E2")
    Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

You can improve the speed performance by using the loop to **locate** the cell above the blank and doing the copy/paste only once.

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```
Sub main()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("B5")
    Do While r.Value <> ""
        Range("E2").Value = r.Value
        Set r = r.Offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub
```